# MediaPlayer memory consumption

Tags: java, android, memory-management

In my android application I created three MediaPlayers

```
MediaPlayer mp1=new MediaPlayer();
MediaPlayer mp2=new MediaPlayer();
MediaPlayer mp3=new MediaPlayer();
```

now, my question is if I create an array in addition like:

```
MediaPlayer mp[]={mp1,mp2,mp3};
```

does it takes up  same memory size as the above 3 media players, or just put some references to mp1,2,3 in a small memory amount?

Also, if somebody knows, how much memory is allocated for one media player?

Comment: no need to create an array like that. you can reset and play a new song with the same media player object

Comment: Yes of course that will consume your memory if you will create multiple player object. you just have to mange your player with play,pause,resume state.@Raghunandan is right. check this state diagram and doc http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Answer (score 0):

The array only stores references to the MediaPlayer objects. It (the array) probably takes about 20 bytes.